# Extracting maximum (x,y) values and initial slope of non-linear fitted glm curves

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, ggplot2, exponential-distribution

I have plotted 8 curves using a log-link Gaussian model, $y=ax \times exp(bx)+ϵ$, for my data. I am not sure how to extract the $max (x,y)$ from each of the fitted curves using the equation, of which I intend to use for statistical analysis later. I am also trying to calculate the initial slope (⍺, increasing part) of each curve if that's possible at all.

[image: Plotted curves (click here)]

If anyone had already done this before, or know of some ways around it, I could really use some help. Below are some of my data and codes I used for plotting the curves. I used `0.0000000001` instead of `0` to fulfill the argument in my codes.

```
rlc <- data.frame(par = c(0.0000000001,6,18,35,61,93,121,195,268, 0.0000000001,6,18,35,61,93,121,195,268),
                 tmp = c(24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27),
                 etr = c(0.06, 1.63, 4.88, 7.70, 9.47, 9.47, 8.07, 6.55, 3.60, 0.06, 1.44, 3.78, 5.06, 5.68, 5.51, 4.35, 3.21, 1.91))

rlc$tmp=as.character(rlc$tmp) #leaving tmp as numerical will result in continuous gradient

glm(etr ~ log(par) + par,
    family=gaussian(link="log"),
    subset=par>0,
    data=rlc)

rlc_plot <- ggplot(rlc, aes(x=par,y=etr, group=tmp, colour=tmp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data=subset(rlc,par>0),
              method="glm",
              formula=y~x + log(x),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args=list(family=gaussian(link="log")))
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, because isn't your "initial slope" estimate precisely the exponential of the intercept term?  Could you explain further this business with "0.0000000001"?  Is that a real observation or something you have created to help with the fitting procedure?  And since the mode is located the point $x=-1/b,$ which is readily computed from your estimate of $b,$ what exactly do you mean by "extrapolate"?

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. I am rather unfamiliar with the equation myself so I am not sure how to produce the parameters that I am looking for. You mean the initial slope would be `exp(bx)`? And `0.0000000001` is not a real observation (zero is the real observation), but in order to fulfill `par>0`, I made it a small number that is close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for your linear predictor is $\eta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 \log(x)$. The maximum of the curve will occur at the maximum of $\eta$, so we need $d\eta/dx=0$:

$$
\begin{split}
0 & = \frac{d\eta}{dx} \\
0 & = \beta_1 + \beta_2/x \\
x & = -\beta_2/\beta_1
\end{split}
$$

The y-value at this point will be 
$$
\begin{split}
& \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x + \beta_2 \log(x)) \\
 = & \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1 (-\beta_2/\beta_1) + \beta_2 \log(-\beta_2/\beta_1)) \\
 = & \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_2(\log(-\beta_2/\beta_1) -1))
\end{split}
$$